# It's possible to upload content to Cloud Storage automatically from Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to load CSV files from Google Drive into BigQuery automatically and I was wondering if it's possible to do it that way:

1. Google Drive Folder
2. Pub/Sub, Cloud Functions, DriveApi... ??
3. Cloud Storage Bucket
4. Bigquery

I have developed a python script that uploads the CSV file stored in Cloud Storage automatically to BigQuery, now I need to create the workflow between Google Drive and Cloud Storage.

I've been researching but really don´t really know how to proceed.

Any hints?

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, your purpose is to store Drive files in Cloud Storage? What did you try till now? Do you have any code you are working on?

Comment: @Iamblichus yep, correct. I've done the "next step" which is the code to send the bucket csv content to BigQuery, and it's actually working properly. But I need to move the content from Drive to Cloud Storage, and I have no clue of how to do it. Maybe using kind of a trigger.. not sure

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is not in my area of expertise, but I guess you should first export the files from Drive (see [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)) and then [upload them to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

Comment: @Iamblichus that's what I need. I need it to be triggered, automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to develop an app to listen for changes, Google App Engine works well here or Cloud Functions.

The app will need to implement the Retrieve Changes logic that makes sense to your use case.

See these Google Drive API docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes

With Drive, I recommend asking whether the OAuth is worth it for any app. Asking your users to submit to a lightweight frontend might be easy and faster to develop.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the answer given in january by @jareyes on this same question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856612/15469537)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google drive API to pull data from google drive and load it to which ever location you want, i.e. GCS, BQ table and so on.
You can refer following [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) to create a code to achieve same.

Comment: I need it the code to be triggered. My idea is to deploy the script on Google Cloud Functions and make it run when a new file is stored in Cloud Storage...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to develop an app to listen for changes, Google App Engine works well here or Cloud Functions.

The app will need to implement the Retrieve Changes logic that makes sense to your use case.

See these Google Drive API docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes

With Drive, I recommend asking whether the OAuth is worth it for any app. Asking your users to submit to a lightweight frontend might be easy and faster to develop.